# Non-null constraints using triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with two optional columns.
When a row is inserted in the table, one of the two columns should not null.

I found this solution for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  FieldA INT,
  FieldB INT
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFieldABNotNull BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.FieldA IS NULL AND NEW.FieldB IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '\'FieldA\' and \'FieldB\' cannot both be null';
  END IF;
END//
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateFieldABNotNull BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.FieldA IS NULL AND NEW.FieldB IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '\'FieldA\' and \'FieldB\' cannot both be null';
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, 10); -- OK
INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (10, NULL); -- OK
INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, NULL); -- gives error
UPDATE foo SET FieldA = NULL; -- gives error
```

How can I translate it for PostgreSQL?

Comment: You only need this ugly workaround in MySQL because it doesn't support check constraints. In Postgres this is way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  FieldA INT,
  FieldB INT,
  CHECK (NOT (FieldA IS NULL AND FieldB IS NULL)));
```

In this way you cannot insert or modify a tuple with both values NULL.

```
teststar=# INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, 10);
INSERT 0 1
teststar=# INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (10, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
teststar=# INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, NULL);
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null).
teststar=# UPDATE foo SET FieldA = NULL; 
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null).
teststar=#
```

Comment: Very simple to understand and use!! Thank you!